# Pandas group by number (instead of time)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In pd.Grouper we can group by time, for example using 10s

```
Time      Count
10:05:03   2
10:05:04   3
10:05:05   4
10:05:11   3
10:05:12   4
```

Will provide the result of:

```
Time  Count
10:05:10  9
10:05:20  7
```

---

I'm looking for the other way around. Can I group the time by count, for example, using 5

```
Count Time (s)
5    (4-3)=1s
5    (11-5)=6s
5    (12-11)=1s
```

---

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: can you explain how did you get count = 5 and corresponding time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you have in mind. Start with a pandas Series `df`:

```
2018-03-14 06:38:46.308425+00:00     2
2018-03-14 06:38:47.308425+00:00     3
2018-03-14 06:38:48.308425+00:00     4
2018-03-14 06:38:54.308425+00:00     3
2018-03-14 06:38:55.308425+00:00     4
dtype: int64
```

Find the indices where the cumulative sum crosses a multiple of 5:

```
df[:] = df.values.cumsum() // 5 * 5
hit5 = (df.diff() == 5).nonzero()[0]
```

In this case it's `array([1, 3, 4])`. Then iterate over those indices and take the difference with the previous index:

```
for i in hit5:
    print(df.index[i] - df.index[i-1])
```

Giving:

```
0 days 00:00:01
0 days 00:00:06
0 days 00:00:01
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_txt = """
Time    Count
10:05:03    2
10:05:04    3
10:05:05    4
10:05:11    3
10:05:12    4"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_txt), sep='\t')
df['Time'] = df.Time.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
df['CumCount'] = df.Count.cumsum()
df['Ind1'] = df.CumCount // 5
df['Ind2'] = df.Ind1.shift()
df['LagTime'] = df.Time.shift()
df.loc[df.Ind1 == df.Ind2, 'LagTime'] = np.nan
df['StartTime'] = df.LagTime.bfill()
out = df.groupby(['StartTime'], as_index=False).last()
out['Time (s)'] = out.Time.values - out.StartTime.values
```

Output:

```
print(out['Time (s)'])
# 0   00:00:01
# 1   00:00:06
# 2   00:00:01
# Name: Time (s), dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```